# Solve the differential equation by making it exact?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with solving this differential equation:

$(3x^2+3e^x\sin y)dx+(x^3\cot y+6e^x\cos y)dy=0$

With $M=3x^2+3e^x\sin y$ and $N = x^3\cot y+6e^x\cos y$,

I have tried to make at exact by taking

$(M_y - N_x)/M$ which yields $\mu(x) = \csc y$

however my answer does not make the DE exact.

Am I doing something wrong or is there another approach that is more efficient?
Any help appreciated thank you :)

Comment: That's what i got from $(M_y-N_x)/M$ by factoring a -3cosy from the numerator and 3siny from the denominator and using the formula $\mu(x)=e^\int_{}^{}f(y)dy

Comment: With f(y) being $(M_y-N_x)/M$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is your integration factor which is wrong. The actual result which needs to be applied here is -

If $$\frac{M_y - N_x}{M} = g(y)$$
then $$\mu(y) = e^{-\int g(y)}$$

When you were solving, you forgot the $-$ sign in the exponential. Keeping this, we get $\mu(y) = \sin y$, and the solution of the differential equation as -
$$x^3\sin y + 3e^x\sin^2 x = C$$